# How does Tortoise SVN store repository files?

Tags: windows, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have been told that the best SVN client for Microsoft Windows is Tortoise SVN.

However, when I install it, adds only items to my shell, i.e. the right-click options when I click on folders.

When I try to check out a folder, it tries to create a repository inside the folder I am working on.

I would prefer my repository to be outside of my work. Is this possible?

Comment: Guys, be nice. This site is for helping newbies as well.

Comment: Sorry if it's a crap question. I kind of knew I could find the manual somewhere but I thought the point of StackOverflow is to become a resource on all topics? When I couldn't find an answer on here I thought I'd ask the question myself.

Comment: Neil is your blood sugar a tad low? Jon I had the same kind of experience the first time I tried SVN/Tortoise, you just need to point it at a repository.

Answer (score 5):

[Ollifant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741652/how-does-tortoise-svn-work/741664#741664)  is correct, but as you are about to create your first repository, I just wanted to add that file:// is not at all a recommended method of accessing the repository in a production environment. In fact, according to the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/) it should not really be regarded as an option at all:

> Do not be seduced by the simple idea
>   of having all of your users access a
>   repository directly via file:// URLs.
>   Even if the repository is readily
>   available to everyone via a network
>   share, this is a bad idea. It removes
>   any layers of protection between the
>   users and the repository: users can
>   accidentally (or intentionally)
>   corrupt the repository database, it
>   becomes hard to take the repository
>   offline for inspection or upgrade, and
>   it can lead to a mess of file
>   permission problems (see the section
>   called “Supporting Multiple Repository
>   Access Methods”). Note that this is
>   also one of the reasons we warn
>   against accessing repositories via
>   svn+ssh://  URLs—from a security
>   standpoint, it's effectively the same
>   as local users accessing via file://,
>   and it can entail all the same
>   problems if the administrator isn't
>   careful.

svnserve is almost always better then file:// access and it really is almost no additional effort to set up.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a repository and using it are two different things.

The "Create repository here" action creates a repository which you can access locally via file://.. syntax or via the svnserve daemon.

The "Checkout" action can be done in any other place. You can either use a local repository, access a repository via http(s) or svnserve.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to run an SVN server of your own that you can then check files into, try [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/). I use it with Tortoise and AnkSVN (all free) and it works great.